# PHP ajax GET data won't send

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple application where i have a table populated with a data from a database, and i have a link in the table that i need it to perform something in PHP when it get clicked, the problem is i've been trying for ever but it is not working here is my code.

HTML/AJAx

```
<script> 


     $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".LogOut").click(function() {
            var log = "LogOut";
            $.ajax ({
                cache: false,
                data: { Log : log },
                success: function( result ) {

                }
            });
        });
    }); 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".Manage").click(function() {
            var logs = this.getAttribute('value');
            $.ajax ({
                cache: false,
                data: { 'sami' : logs },
                success: function( result ) {

                }
            });
        });
    }); 

             </script>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['sami'])){ 
    echo "<script>alert('Addition Successfull !!.');</script>";
    $sql = "select UID,Valid from users where Email='".$_GET['Sari']."';";
    if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
        if($result->num_rows){ 
            $raw = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if($raw['Valid'] === '1'){
                $_SESSION["UID"]= $raw['UID'];
                header("Location:manage.php"); /* Redirect browser */
            }else{
                header("Location:manage.php");
            }
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['Log'])){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

the thing is, the first ajax works as charming which is (logOut), but the other one that sends "sami" IS NOT working at all.

After every one was complaining about URL the ajax sends to the same page, but nonetheless i added url still did not work.
Thanks

Best Regards

Comment: You don't provide `url`. To what page your data will be sent? To __nowhere__?

Comment: the thing is the first one is working as its without a url, plus i tried url no luck.

Comment: And how did you check that there's no luck?

Comment: If you don't provide a URL it will submit to the current URL, so your first code sample may end up working through sheer luck

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the console? What is this line returning, 
  var logs = this.getAttribute('value'); ?

Comment: Dude, it sends to the same page, the first chunk of ajax works without a url, the second one is the same chunk but different GET value, also send to the same page, plus i have tried adding url and it did not work. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @kevinP no errors at console the logs return an ID value which is typically a number.

Comment: Is the click being triggered? 
Add console.log("Test") and see if the click goes through
   $(".Manage").click(function() {
       console.log("Test");
       // your other ajax code
})

Comment: @KevinP yes it's triggered. thanks

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: In your network panel, does the AJAX request show up at all?

Comment: @KevinP no do you mean in the console, if yes no its not showing.

Comment: You can't redirect the browser from PHP when using AJAX. That just tells AJAX to get the `result` from that new URL.

Comment: @Barmar the thing is i'm just trying to send GET data.

Comment: @SariLakkis I understand that. It has nothing to do with the fact that `header("Location: manage.php")` won't redirect the browser because you're using AJAX.

Comment: You cannot use `header` to redirect once the headers have been sent (AKA after an `echo`)

Comment: @Barmar Neither that, I'm just trying to receive The GET value and echo the first line to see if its working or not, everything else can be changed.

Comment: The Javascript isn't doing anything with `result`.

Comment: @Barmar if i print result it will print the html page again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the PHP code so that it exits after printing the AJAX result. Otherwise you'll fall through to the code that prints the full HTML page.

```
if(isset($_GET['sami'])){ 
    echo "<script>alert('Addition Successfull !!.');</script>";
    $sql = "select UID,Valid from users where Email='".$_GET['Sari']."';";
    if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
        if($result->num_rows){ 
            $raw = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if($raw['Valid'] === '1'){
                $_SESSION["UID"]= $raw['UID'];
                header("Location:manage.php"); /* Redirect browser */
            }else{
                header("Location:manage.php");
            }
        }
    }
    exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['Log'])){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, did that still same issue, the thin is the ajax "Log" is working perfectly, and i have a couple of other ajaxes in other pages working perfectly the same way!!

Answer (score -1):

Your sql statement uses the variable $_GET['Sari'] rather than $_GET['sami'] and your ajax request is using 'sami'.  Replace 'Sari' with 'sami'

Comment: It's not even getting to that point, iam aware of that error, but it does not even pass the if statement.

Comment: Dump your get and your post variable to make sure one of them is getting set.  I'm not sure which one ajax defaults to, but you didn't specify one or the other.  print_r($_GET); print_r($_POST).  Check to see if sami is in there.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: sami  thats what i get

Comment: Do you know if logs has data in it?  I would also specify what type of request you're trying to make just to be sure either get or post, then dump the entire get and post variable to verify.